# Vim: faster way to select blocks of text in visual mode

Tags: vim

I have been using vim for quite some time and am aware that selecting blocks of text in visual mode is as simple as <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and moving the arrow key up or down line-by-line until I reach the end of the block of text that I want selected.

My question is - is there a faster way in visual mode to select a block of text for example by <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> followed by specifying the line number in which I want the selection to stop? (via `:35` for example, where 35 is the line number I want to select up to - this obviously does not work so my question is to find how if something similar to this can be done...)

Comment: +1 Good question as I have found myself doing something like this often. I am wondering if perhaps this isn't the place start using using `v%` or `v/pattern` or something else?

Comment: vip select inner paragraph vis select inner sentence.

Comment: `V35G` will visually select from current line to line 35, also `V10j` or `V10k` will visually select the next or previous 10 lines

Comment: @Stephan, that's just what I was looking for. Thanks!!

Comment: for line selecting I use shortcut: `nnoremap <Space> V`. When in visual line mode just right-click with mouse to define selection (at least on linux it is so). Anyway, more effective than with keyboard only.

Comment: I found the [vim fandom](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Selecting_blocks_of_paragraphs) page most helpful: ```vip```.  @SergioAraujo Do you want to make an answer out of it?

Comment: @Stephan  for `V35G`  I got `Not an editor command: V35G`

Answer (score 261, accepted):

In addition to what others have said, you can also expand your selection using pattern searches.

For example, <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> will select from your current position to the next instance of "foo." If you actually wanted to expand to the *next* instance of "foo," on line 35, for example, just press <kbd>n</kbd> to expand selection to the next instance, and so on.

#### update

I don't often do it, but I know that some people use marks extensively to make visual selections. For example, if I'm on line 5 and I want to select to line 35, I might press <kbd>m</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> to place mark `a` on line 5, then <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>5</kbd> to move to line 35. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> to enter linewise visual mode, and finally <kbd>`</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> to select back to mark `a`.

Comment: If you need to include the pattern you can use `v/foo/e`. The `e` stands for "end" of the matched pattern.

Comment: And you can modify from that line with offsets:  V/foo/+5 or V/foo/-5 (I'm using linewise visual mode like the author).

Comment: What would you do if you wanted to select the range of text matching your search; i.e: find and select (whole word) your search term?

Comment: @DanielPark To select the current word, use `v` `i` `w`. If you want to select the current contiguous non-whitespace, use `v` `i` `Shift`+`w`. The difference would be when the caret is here `MyCla|ss.Method`, the first combo would select `MyClass` and second would select the whole thing.

Comment: Thanks. Found that also using `v i w s` allows you to effectively do a "replace" operation.

Comment: @Daniel Park, how about `c i w`?

Comment: To go along with the "update" section of this answer, note that with a mark there's no reason to do the visual selection at all if the action you want to take is simple: `ma (move) v'ad`, for instance, is equivalent to simply `ma (move) d'a`.

Comment: This is super helpful, I've been trying to figure out a way to highlight something like `5.00m` ... which Vim does not interpret as a word (or a sentence). Starting with the cursor on 5 and doing `v/m` {enter} works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: Thanks. the `v/pattern` is really helpful. I should have voted you twice if I could.
I will use `v/;` a lot when I write code.

Answer (score 131):

```
G                       Goto line [count], default last line, on the first
                        non-blank character linewise.  If 'startofline' not
                        set, keep the same column.
                        G is a one of jump-motions.
```

V35G achieves what you want

Answer (score 115):

Vim is a language.  To really understand Vim, you have to know the language.  Many commands are verbs, and vim also has objects and prepositions.

```
V100G
V100gg
```

This means "select the current line up to and including line 100."

Text objects are where a lot of the power is at.  They introduce more objects with prepositions.

```
Vap
```

This means "select around the current paragraph", that is select the current paragraph and the blank line following it.

```
V2ap
```

This means "select around the current paragraph and the next paragraph."

```
}V-2ap
```

This means "go to the end of the current paragraph and then visually select it and the preceding paragraph."

Understanding Vim as a language will help you to get the best mileage out of it.

After you have selecting down, then you can combine with other commands:

```
Vapd
```

With the above command, you can select around a paragraph and delete it.  Change the `d` to a `y` to copy or to a `c` to change or to a `p` to paste over.

Once you get the hang of how all these commands work together, then you will eventually not need to visually select anything.  Instead of visually selecting and then deleting a paragraph, you can just delete the paragraph with the `dap` command.

Comment: }V-2ap Use of -2 is really smart.

Answer (score 47):

`v35G` will select everything from the cursor up to line 35.

`v` puts you in select mode, `35` specifies the line number that you want to `G` go to.

You could also use `v}` which will select everything up to the beginning of the next paragraph.

Comment: As an alternative to v} I usually prefer  vip  (which I recall via the memory aid "very important paragraph")

Answer (score 16):

For selecting number of lines:

shift+v 9j - select 10 lines

Comment: For small ranges this is good, especially when paired with `:set rnu`

Answer (score 13):

simple just press <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>line number</kbd> <kbd>gg</kbd>

example: your current line to line 41
Just press <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>41</kbd> <kbd>gg</kbd>

Comment: why does this work

Answer (score 12):

`Shift+V n j` or `Shift+V n k`

This selects the current line and the next/previous `n` lines. I find it very useful.

Comment: This is a simple way I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

`v%`

will select the whole block.

Play with also:

`v}`, `vp`, `vs`, etc.

See help:

`:help text-objects`

which lists the different ways to select letters, words, sentences, paragraphs, blocks, and so on.

Comment: If the use case is selecting block within a markup language content like JSON, `V%` is definitely the fastest way to achieve this goal. Thanks!

Comment: I will complete your proposal with `Vat` for markup language with tags like HTML or XML.

Answer (score 9):

You can press `vi}` to select the block surrounded with `{}` brackets where your cursor is currently located.

It doesn't really matter where you are inside that block (just make sure you are in the outermost one). Also you can change `{` to anything that has a pair like `)` or `]`.

Answer (score 7):

v 35 j

text added for 30 character minimum

Answer (score 5):

Text objects: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Creating_new_text_objects

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#text-objects

Answer (score 4):

You can always just use antecedent numbers to repeat actions:

- In visual mode, type <kbd>3</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd> and the cursor will move down 35 times, selecting the next 35 lines
- In normal mode:

  - delete 35 lines <kbd>3</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>
  - paste 35 times <kbd>3</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>
  - undo 35 changes <kbd>3</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>u</kbd>
  - etc.

Answer (score 1):

} means move cursor to next paragraph. so, use `v}` to select entire paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

It could come in handy to know:

In order to select the same ammount of lines for example use `1v`
You should have done some modification to be able to use `1v`, blockwise or linewise.

Today I saw this amazing tip from [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/11218/7339):

```
 :5mark < | 10mark > | normal gvV
 :5mark < | 10mark > | normal gv
```

You can also reset the visual block boundaries doing so:

```
m< .......... sets the visual mode start point
m> .......... sets the visual mode end point
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this with fold in indent mode :

<kbd>v</kbd> open Visual mode anywhere on the block

<kbd>za</kbd><kbd>za</kbd> toogle it twice

Answer (score 1):

Presss `V` to select the current line and enter the line number on keyboard and the press `G`.

Answer (score 0):

For selecting all in visual:
Type Esc to be sure yor are in normal mode

```
:0
```

type ENTER to go to the beginning of file

```
vG
```

Comment: You can use `gg` in normal mode to go to the first line also.

Answer (score 0):

Text-objects will help you, especially if you don't want to count lines manually, but VIM has no native text-object based on indentation.

Thankfully, [this plugin](https://github.com/michaeljsmith/vim-indent-object) does just that.

Answer (score 0):

To visually select the current paragraph I use `{V}`. It's intuitive for me.

*Vscode* does support a vim mode, though it is limited. `Vap` does not work.