# Vim: Quickly select rectangular blocks of text in visual-block mode

Tags: vim

I'm looking for a fast way to select a block of text in visual-block mode. I deal with files of this nature:

```
aaaa bbbb cccc
aaaa bbbb cccc
aaaa bbbb cccc

dddd Xeee ffff
dddd eeee ffff
dddd eeee ffff

gggg hhhh iiii
gggg hhhh iiii
gggg hhhh iiii
```

My goal is to select the middle block in visual-block mode. I would do:

1. Navigate to the corner (where the X is)
2. Ctrl-V
3. 'e' to extend selection to the end of block
4. 'jj' or '2j' to extend the selection downward to the bottom of the block.

I'm looking for an alternative to (4) that, similar to 'e', would move to the last row of the block. In this simple example 'jj' is not too inconvenient, but sometimes these are large blocks.

There's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406949/vim-faster-way-to-select-blocks-of-text-in-visual-mode) , but that involves jumping a pre-determined number of lines. Is there a way to do this, again an analog to 'e', but moving row-wise instead of column-wise?  Thanks!

Comment: I think using a mark won't be too inconvenient...

Answer (score 9):

Starting on the `X`, you could do this with `<C-v>}kee`:

1. `<C-v>` – start blockwise visual mode
2. `}` – go to the end of the paragraph (that motion supposedly provides the benefit of this rather involved combo)
3. `k` – one above to exclude the empty line
4. `ee` – move the cursor from the first column to the end of the inner block.

Answer (score 5):

I had some fun trying to make a function "select Visual block around cursor".

```
function! ContiguousVBlock()
  let [lnum, vcol] = [line('.'), virtcol('.')]
  let [top, bottom] = [lnum, lnum]
  while matchstr(getline(top-1), '\%'.vcol.'v.') =~# '\S'
    let top -= 1
  endwhile
  while matchstr(getline(bottom+1), '\%'.vcol.'v.') =~# '\S'
    let bottom += 1
  endwhile

  let lines = getline(top, bottom)
  let [left, right] = [vcol, vcol]
  while len(filter(map(copy(lines), 'matchstr(v:val,"\\%".(left-1)."v.")'),'v:val=~#"\\S"')) == len(lines)
    let left -= 1
  endwhile
  while len(filter(map(copy(lines), 'matchstr(v:val,"\\%".(right+1)."v.")'),'v:val=~#"\\S"')) == len(lines)
    let right += 1
  endwhile

  call setpos('.', [0, top, strlen(matchstr(lines[0], '^.*\%'.left.'v.')), 0])
  execute "normal! \<C-V>"
  call setpos('.', [0, bottom, strlen(matchstr(lines[-1], '^.*\%'.right.'v.')), 0])
endfunction
nnoremap <Leader>vb :<C-U>call ContiguousVBlock()<CR>
```

You can try it with `<Leader>vb`: It should select any contiguous non-whitespace rectangular block around the cursor. The vertical axis is preferred.

Maybe I'll improve it later, but for now you can try if it solves your problem, if you like.

As an alternative to my homegrown attempt, you could try the popular plugin ***[textobj-word-column](https://github.com/coderifous/textobj-word-column.vim)***. It gives you text objects `ac` `ic` `aC` `iC` to select a column of words or WORDs.

Comment: +1 textobj-word-column does make this kind of thing pretty simple

Comment: @PeterRincker Really? I always feel bad recommending textobj-word-column, because it's never worked for me ... it's a "please-do-what-I-mean" kind of plugin, and it never seemed to understand what I meant. I got rid of it in the end.

Comment: I agree on the "please do what i mean" plugin bit. It can be frustrating. It works well when in the "obvious" cases. Which I believe this is. I personally have fork that I have made it that uses surrounding boundaries to help reduce its eagerness. However I am not sure it is ready for prime time. I should really put it up on github

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to write this nice function. Actually, the textobj-word-column plugin works very well for my needs, having a little more flexibility.

Answer (score 2):

Start visual mode with `v`. Then select inner paragraph with `ip`. Enter visual block mode with `<C-v>`. Now just go to the end of the block with `e`s as required.

Starting from the bottom right of the block is the same thing, but instead of `e`, use `w`.